# How to change the value of a Textview using buttons to iterate through an ArrayList?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, arraylist, textview

I have a fragment that uses a Filereader to read and parse a .txt file into the fragment and store this data as a custom ArrayList called "instructions". I want to display the value of each index of the Arraylist in a Textview by iterating over the Arraylist using a forward button or backward button. The problem I am finding is that I cannot increment the index of the arraylist simply by incrementing the value of i in the onclick method. I was wondering if there is a different approach to be taken.

Here is the code below

```
public class pneumothorax_fr_flashcard_view extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {
    private static final String TAG = "flashcard view";
    fileReader reader = new fileReader(); /* this is the file parser*/
    int i = 0;
    
    /*establishing context - this is needed to pass the file into the fragment and parse it as an arraylist */
    private Context mContext;
    @Override
    public void onAttach(@NonNull Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mContext = null;
    }


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.pneumothorax_flashcard_view,container,false);
        /*initialise the ArrayList and load in the parsed file*/
        ArrayList <fileReader.InstructionList> instructions = reader.loadFile(mContext,"Pneumothorax_copy.txt");
        

        /*initialise the textview and set the initial string*/
        TextView flashcardBox = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.flashcardBox);
        flashcardBox.setText(instructions.get(i).toString());



        /*initialise buttons*/

        ImageButton forwardButton = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.forwardButton);
        ImageButton backwardButton = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.backwardButton);
        ImageButton yesButton = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.yesButton);
        ImageButton noButton = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.noButton);
        forwardButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        backwardButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        yesButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        noButton.setOnClickListener(this);





        return view;
    }

    
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.forwardButton:
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Next button has been clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                i++; //WHAT DO I DO HERE???//
                break;
            case R.id.backwardButton:
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Back button has been clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case R.id.yesButton:
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Yes button has been clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case R.id.noButton:
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "No button has been clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: plase show how 'fileReader' looks like and also fileReader.InstructionList

Comment: It doesn't really matter, because the class just gives you an arraylist, the issue which i'm having is mainly thinking about a way to iterate, not that the iteration isn't working

Answer (score 0):

I would change the onCreateView method:

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.pneumothorax_flashcard_view,container,false);
    /*initialise the ArrayList and load in the parsed file*/
    ArrayList <fileReader.InstructionList> instructions = reader.loadFile(mContext,"Pneumothorax_copy.txt");


    /*initialise the textview and set the initial string*/
    TextView flashcardBox = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.flashcardBox);
    flashcardBox.setText(instructions.get(i).toString());



    /*initialise buttons*/

    ImageButton forwardButton = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.forwardButton);
    ImageButton backwardButton = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.backwardButton);
    ImageButton yesButton = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.yesButton);
    ImageButton noButton = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.noButton);
    forwardButton.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        //add sth to handle i>instructions.length
        flashcardBox.setText(instructions.get(i).toString());
    });
    backwardButton.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        i--;
        //add sth to handle i<0
        flashcardBox.setText(instructions.get(i).toString());
    });
    yesButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    noButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    return view;
}
```

This way you have access to your instructions array.

Another way to achieve what you want would be to add a class variable that holds the instructions `ArrayList` but if you only use it to show the value in the `TextView`, I would stick to the first solution.